# What is a good database design to use in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android application which stores predictions for to-be-winners in every match of a tournament by a group of people and tells them their points as well as of others based on the overall correct guesses. Had I used table based databases, I would have used following kind of database design.

```
Match (Match_id, Team1, Team2, Winner, Timestamp);
Person (Username, Full_name, Password);
Prediction_table (Username, Match_id, Winner_Prediction);
```

Then I could have queried using SQL to get the results.

But now I am using Firebase which supports JSON structure. Which database design is best to fulfill this purpose?

I also have following two database designs in mind, but am unable to decide which one would solve the requirement properly.

```
Matches {
Match1: { Person1: Predicted_Team1, ..., PersonM: Predicted_TeamM },
Match2: {...},
...
MatchN: {...}
}
```

and

```
Persons {
Person1: {Match1: Prediction1, ... MatchN: PredictionN},
...
PersonM: {...}
}
```

Comment: Did you read this?
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html

Comment: I also recommend this article nowadays: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/